# Seeing contents of `wasm_bindgen::JsError` in tests

Tags: rust, wasm-bindgen

I am writing a unit test for function like this, which compiles just fine:

```
#[wasm_bindgen]
pub fn my_fn(params_js: JsValue) -> Result<JsValue, JsError> {
    // ...
}
```

But in my test, if a call to `my_fn` fails, I'm unable to see any details about the error.

```
#[wasm_bindgen_test]
pub fn my_test() {
    // ...
    let js_return = my_fn(params).unwrap();
    // ...
}
```

> `JsError` cannot be formatted using `{:?}` because it doesn't implement `Debug`

I've even tried to format a message:

```
let js_return = my_fn(params)
    .map_err(|err| format!("Failed to get setting: {}", err))
    .unwrap();
```

> `JsError` cannot be formatted with the default formatter

How can we get something useful from a `JsError` error result when calling a bindgenned function in tests?

Answer (score 0):

I see there is [an implementation](https://rustwasm.github.io/wasm-bindgen/api/wasm_bindgen/struct.JsError.html#impl-From%3CJsError%3E-for-JsValue) to convert a `JsError` into a `JsValue` which does implement `Debug`. So you might get a sensible error message with this:

```
let js_return = my_fn(params)
    .map_err(JsValue::from)
    .unwrap();
```